# add a newline character to an existence registry at CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I don't know if this question is so stupid but...

How can i add a newline character to a database registry?
I just want to add a new line character after the input that is shown to the user in the edit or add form.

For example:

```
//edit view
echo $this->Form->input('reply_above');
```

I want to send a mail with some information and this string should be at the top separate from the rest of the mail message by a newline.

I have tried this at the edit action in the controller:

```
$this->request->data['Setting']['reply_separator'].= '<br />';
```

But then, when i use the mail function it shows the `<br />` instead of printing it. (and i really don't want to send the mail in HTML format)

The texts stored on the database don't use a `<br />` for new lines. What do they use instead? I have also tried `\n` but it doesn't work either.

Thanks.

## UPDATE

I could be able to add a new line doing this in the edit controller before saving the data:

```
$this->request->data['Setting']['reply_separator'].="               
";
```

But it really doesn't look like a good solution plus i can not add more than one newline with this method.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your new line character: `"\n"`.

Edit: Be sure to use double quotes not single quote.

Comment: Ok. The problem was that i was using `'\n'` instead of double quotes. This worked fine `$email->send($x."\n".$y);`  but this didn't `$email->send($x.'\n'.$y);`

Comment: You need to learn the difference between a string and literal in PHP :)

Comment: Ok, suddently it stop working. I didnt change anything and it no longer works with `"\n"`...